# How to dynamically retrieve ANY report in a folder using package.xml

Tags: metadata, ant, eclipse, custom-reports, package.xml

In ANT or Eclipse I want to retrieve ALL reports of a given folder WITHOUT declaring each report in `package.xml` line-by-line expressis verbis. What Eclipse is generation, when I subscribe to a folder is:

```
<types>
    <members>elfBC000</members>
    <members>elfBC000/BC456B</members>
    <members>elfBC000/BC460B</members>
    <!-- large number of extra lines naming more reports come here... -->
    <name>Report</name>
</types>
```

This is very hard to maintain, when reports and API-Names are changing frequently and the number of reports is huge. I would like to retrieve them more like it's done for other metadata-type like e. g. APEX-classes:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
```

Now I've tried that for reports but failed:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Report</name>
</types>
```

or

```
<types>
    <members>elfBC000</members>
    <members>elfBC000/*</members>
    <name>Report</name>
</types>
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: yeah even I faced this issue didn't found much but after that I just used https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/ app to build the package.xml

Comment: I use this script to print all reports with their folder names and prepare package.xml to retrieve. https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sfdcnoob/fa0423dc198c8c30d6ba9a66cff0e8d6/raw/4bba980fcf8f7ee623ca6c3c2dbe2c04114a7bf5/RetrieveAllReports.cls

Answer (score 1):

Here is alternative way to retrieve all reports.

You can’t use the wildcard (*) symbol to retrieve all reports in package.xml,

query all your reports in your report object (SELECT Name, DeveloperName, FolderName FROM Report) using Workbench/Developer Console and form it in your package.xml

Refer:
http://theblogreaders.com/retrieve-unfiled-public-reports-using-salesforce-package-xml/

Thanks & Regards,
Sakthivel Madesh

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler way you could list and get package.xml for all your reports you need.

1. Login to https://www.packmagix.com using Salesforce Oauth2 connection.
2. Select component type as 'Report'
3. Then select all the reports you want in your package.xml and  click on 'Add to Package' button.
4. Click on 'Download Package.xml' or 'Download Package.zip' button depending on your requirement. It will download package.xml or package.zip respectively.

[image: Report selection for package.xml]